# Working from raw source data from a filepath containing spaces using make and Makefiles

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile, data-science, gnu-make

I have a repository that uses python scripts and a Makefile. I want to have a setup procedure that
allows them to easily set up an environment and copy in the necessary data files from our server.

The problem with including the source data files in the Makefile is that the company server uses 
spaces in the drive name, which make doesn't like very much, so I can list those files as dependencies
for the target output file.

My current Makefile basically does only the following:

```
.PHONY : all
all : output.csv

.PHONY : copy_data_to_local_folder
copy_data_to_local_folder :
    python copyfile.py "V:\\Server Path\\With Spaces\\Inputs 1.csv" local/inputs1.csv
    python copyfile.py "V:\\Server Path\\With Spaces\\Inputs 2.csv" local/inputs2.csv

output.csv : combine_data.R local/inputs1.csv local/inputs2.csv
    Rscript $^ $@
```

The `copy_data_to_local_folder` part is just to get the data to the local directory, but it isn't included 
in the DAG leading to the production of `output.csv` (i.e. `all : output.csv copy_data_to_local_folder`) or else
the target would need to run everytime.

My solution ideas are the following, but I'm not sure what's best practice:

1. **Use a different make tool.** I could use `Luigi` in Python or `Drake` in R, but I would prefer to keep 
   the tool somewhat more generalized.
2. **Run a setup script to copy in files.** I assume there would be a way to run the file copying scripts
   as part of the environment setup, but I am unfamiliar with how to do this.

I am not sure about the best way to do this. I want to be able to share the code with a co-worker and have them
be able to get up and running on their system without too much messing around to configure. Is there a best
practice for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fix would be:

```
local/inputs1.csv :
    python copyfile.py "V:\\Server Path\\With Spaces\\Inputs 1.csv" $@
local/inputs2.csv :
    python copyfile.py "V:\\Server Path\\With Spaces\\Inputs 2.csv" $@

output.csv : combine_data.R | local/inputs1.csv local/inputs2.csv
    Rscript $^ $| $@
```

Note that `local/inputs1.csv` and `local/inputs2.csv` are made order-only prerequisites, so that they are only made when they don't exist (unless you'd like to copy them every time the makefile is run). Automatic variable `$|` refers to order-only prerequisites, they aren't included in `$^`.

Comment: I had no idea this functionality existed, and this has been hugely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @teepee Those 2 repetetive rules can probably be replaced with 1 pattern rule (one-liner): `local/inputs%.csv : ; python copyfile.py "V:\\Server Path\\With Spaces\\Inputs $*.csv" $@`

Comment: Thanks, Maxim. I guess the problem with that would be that the local file name will retain any of its spaces, since I won't be able to specify a different name with that rule, right?

Comment: @teepee That pattern rule creates files with the same local names as your original rules - `local/inputsN.csv`.