# Is there any practice to generate state file as Makefile target

Tags: makefile

By default Makefile targets are all 'file' target. In order to get it work for non-file target, there needs some workaround.

For example:

1. There is a file_upload task which ensures a local file is uploaded to remote server
2. There is task_a and task_b, which both depend on file_upload task
3. In a full job run, task_a and task_b are called in sequence, but not from same make execution

Assume the file on remote server won't change by others.

Can we leverage Makefile here to ensure file_upload is not called twice in one full job run?
A draft solution is:

```
.state/file_upload:
  ensure file uploaded
  create .state/file_upload
task_a: .state/file_upload
task_b: .state/file_upload
.PHONY task_a task_b
```

Makefile works well for 'ensure desired state' case when target is filesystem. The question is, for non-file targets, is there some usage in practice?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/60743710/412080

Comment: I don't know what you're looking for.  You seem to have put the answer right in the question.  Make deals with files using filesystem modification times.  If you need to track state for something that is not a file, you have to translate that thing's state into files and manipulate their modification times to reflect that state.